# How to localize view in xcode4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, xcode4

I want to **localize** my iOS project in **xcode4**. In xcode4 this seems to be very simple. In the utility sidebar there is a localization panel where I can add languages.

Adding a language I get following structure:

[image]

I want to localize a button. So I open `MainWindow.xib (German)` and just edit the title of the button. But when I run my project on both device or simulator I always get the english version even if it is set to German.

Where is the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the app from the device or simulator. If you've launched it before you've added the localization there is still a MainWindow.xib in the root file structure of the project.
If you deploy from Xcode files are only added, never removed.

So you have three files now.

```
MainWindow.xib 
de.lproj/MainWindow.xib 
en.lproj/MainWindow.xib
```

And as long there is a file in the root folder iOS doesn't look into the language specific folders.

Answer (score 0):

Go into settings on the iPhone or Simulator and change the International from English to German, then restart the app.

Comment: I run it on my device which has all set to german, but I get the MainWIndow.xib (English)